# How to remove lines starting with specific character?

Tags: notepad++

I need to remove all lines starting with number 8.

My document contains few hundred lines. All starting with the number 8 need to be removed.

Answer (score 6):

Go to "Search" -> "Replace" and check the "Regular Expression" on:

```
^[8].*
```

replace with `" "`

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185983/delete-all-lines-starting-with-or-in-notepad which details how to also remove the resulting blank line by adding \r, \n or \r\n to the end of the pattern, depending on which line ending your file is using,